# How can I check on a result from a php script that is returned with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I got a login script (not yet encrypted and all) which posts to a PHP script, this script then returns a result, either that the credentials are correct, that they are wrong or that a user needs to fill in 1 or both of the fields when empty.

After this I want to redirect to a page according to the result (if the credentials are correct). But not of course when it is wrong or when 1 or both of the fields are empty.

How can I check for that in ajax?

This is what I have now in my PHP script:

```
$conn = new Connection;

$username = $_POST['username'];
$userpassword = $_POST['userpassword'];

if(empty($username) && empty($userpassword)){
  echo 'Vul een gebruikersnaam en wachtwoord in';
}else if(empty($username)){
  echo 'Vul een gebruikersnaam in';
}else if(empty($userpassword)){
  echo 'Vul een wachtwoord in';
}else{
  //Both filled in, begin logincode:
  $getuser = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$conn->real_escape_string($username)."'";
  $getusercon = $conn->query($getuser);
  $getuser = $getusercon->fetch_assoc();

  if($userpassword == $getuser['password']){
    if($getuser['rights'] == '1'){
      $_SESSION['user'] = 'admin';
       $userdata = array(
         'userdata' => $_SESSION['user'],
      );
     echo json_encode($userdata);
    }else{
      $_SESSION['user'] = 'user';
       $userdata = array(
         'userdata' => $_SESSION['user'],
      );
     echo json_encode($userdata);
    }
  }else{
    echo 'Wachtwoord en gebruikersnaam komen niet overeen';
  }
}
```

This is my ajax:

```
// Login Ajax Code
$( "#content" ).on("submit", "#loginform", function( event ) {
  // Stop normal form behaviour
  event.preventDefault();
  // Retrieve input fields and their values
  var $form = $( this ),
  $username = $form.find( "input[name='username']" ).val(),
  $userpassword = $form.find( "input[name='userpassword']" ).val(),
  url = $form.attr( "action" );
  // Post above values to the action of the form
  var posting = $.post( url, { username: $username, userpassword: $userpassword} );
  // Show result in a div
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    $( "#loginresult" ).empty().slideDown('fast').append( data );
  }, "json");
});
```

I added the last `, "json"` part to try and get the session content back, which kind of works.

I see this in my `loginresult` box when I login correctly with an admin account: `{"userdata":"admin"}`

How can I decode that to use in my ajax code? The problem is I only need to decode it when it's json of course, not when it's a normal message that shows one or both fields are empty. Maybe all responses need to be json?

How can I for example redirect to a certain page when `userdata` contains `admin` ?

Comment: All messages need to be in `JSON` format for consistency.

Comment: `How can I check for that in ajax?` by returning the relevant info in the response from the PHP, and checking what values are returned. Just like you determine the result of any function you execute in a computer program, really. And yes it would be best if all your possible responses are in JSON format, then the ajax request can read them cleanly in all cases, without having to work out what the format is first.

Comment: You can take this JSON as reference/example- If login is a success, then `{"login_result":"success","data":{"userdata":"admin"}}`. So, while parsing JSON in your JS code, you know that if login result is a success, then you need to redirect, else, the rest part follows.

Comment: Of course if you want to be more REST-ful then if there's an error in the user input, you can also change the HTTP status code accordingly - e.g. 403 if the user doesn't have access to the requested data, 400 for a validation error, etc. The ajax client can detect that as well and use it to decide what to do next.

Comment: Try using a framework like [slim](https://www.slimframework.com) (light one) so you can render a page passing parameters at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

All the responses must have the same format, JSON in this case.
So, in Javascript, you can do something like:

```
obj = JSON.parse(data);
```